# Services manager for Debian to change whether a service starts onboot or not (mysql,apache,networking,network-manager,gdm,xdm,etc)

Tags: debian, boot, services

This question is about finding a GUI or ncurses or whatever services manager for a Debian desktop. Something like this:

### Mac example

[image: Services manager on Windows]

### Windows example

[image: Services manager on Mac]

### The ideas what it should do

The thing should be able to manage anything 'sudo service  start/stop' handles, including

- mysql
- network-manager
- networking
- gdm, xdm
- apache2

And it should

- show description for each service
- let me set the startup type (whether it starts on-boot automatically or I have to start it manually)

### The ideas what it should not do

- Not be rc.d. I would be somewhat interested in ways which don't involve reading what rc.d is.
- Not be bum. I tried it.

  - names of some services are replaced with gibberish (Bum doesn't start for me anymore so I don't have a way to demo this problem; providing with a generic screenshot)
  - they don't have descriptions, and
  - there is no way to change the manual or automatic start-up type (i.e. tell mysql to stop starting onboot)
    [image: BUM]

### OpenSUSE example

[image: OpenSUSE example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some that I know of. I am not sure what you mean about avoiding `rc.d` though.

1. `sysv-rc-conf`

   [image]

   The numbers on the `service` row refer to [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux_Standard_Base_specification).
2. `systemadm`, installable on debian with `sudo apt-get install systemd-gui`:

   [image]
3. Gnome services manager, `services-admin`, this may be what you refer to as `bum` but I am not sure.

   [image]
4. A [Perl script](http://paste.manjaro.org/1043/) I found [posted on a forum](http://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=272.0). It probably needs some tweaking (read the forum post) but could serve as a good starting point for you to play around with.

   [image]

Comment: 1) I don't need to edit runlevels of a service. Only to tell it whether to start onboot or not. So if I set it to not boot, I will have to **remember** what runlevels it had to enable it again. However there is only one runlevel which would make sense for a certain service. Editing it is not needed. Remembering is hard and redundant. 2) There is no systemd-admin package on Ubuntu. 3) Does set a service to [not] start on boot. 3) Per the script, "As of now, there is no actual functionality, it just scans the  services; Makes a GUI and when the Apply button is pressed prints what would be done."

Comment: @Gryllida 1) Editing the runlevels of a service _is_ how you tell it to start at boot or not, look up [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel). You do not need to *remember*, you just need to understand what runlevels are and how they work. The runlevel you are interested in is probably 5. Those services with 5 checked "start on boot". 2) What is `systemd-admin`? I said `systemd-gui`. 3) I said it could serve as a _starting point_. As I said, *read* the forum post. 4) You'd think a simple "thank you for your time" might have fit somewhere in your last comment.

Comment: Thank you for your time! (the comment length was quite limiting, I had 0 chars left! ;-) A) systemd-gui isn't found in the repos either..... B) the runlevels stuff is, wouldn't it be up to a **packager** to tell the runlevel, so i simply tell whether to trigger the run or not?

Comment: Packager is the person who packages something (i.e. packages mysql). /They/ know what runlevel it belongs to. I should have an option of not caring and just using the default runlevel, right?

Comment: No, it is not up to them. The package will be set up with its default settings. Mysql, for example will start on boot by default. It is then up to the susadmin to tweak as desired.

Comment: Thanks. :) Do you have an example when it's useful to tweak it?

Comment: Well I think you have given one :). You tweak it when you want to change the default behavior, I assume that is what you want to do. If you don't want  a service to start automatically you set _all_ its runlevels to off, if you only want a service to be activated when you do a normal login (network, GUI) you set it to start on runlevel 5 alone. Oh, and "susadmin" is the sysadmin, darned phone keyboard...

Comment: I don't want to change default behaviour, just turn a service on or off... (I know this isn't a forum/chat, but I'd like to know what you think :-)

Comment: To turn a service off: `sudo service mysql stop`, to start `sudo service mysql stop`. To change its default behavior either edit the links in `/etc/rc5.d` or (much better) use [update-rc.d](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/how-start-applications-boot-debian).

Answer (score 0):

**[Systemd Manager](https://github.com/mmstick/systemd-manager)** (For systemd only)

> This application exists to allow the user to manage their systemd
>   services via a GTK3 GUI. Not only are you able to make changes to the
>   enablement and running status of each of the units, but you will also
>   be able to view and modify their unit files.

[image: systemd-manager]

Github: https://github.com/mmstick/systemd-manager